# Not able to download file from google drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

We are using google drive api to download the content, which was working fine from last 2 years, Now we started facing below error:

> Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1
>
> **403 Forbidden**
>
> Your client does not have permission.

steps to reproduce:

Get API:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/<FILE_ID>?alt=media&source=downloadUrl
Headers : Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

Content created on google drive is getting downloaded, while content uploaded to drive from the local machine is not getting downloaded via API.

Any help would be appreciated. We have scope drive.readonly granted.

Comment: 403 ForbiddenMeans that the call you are making has not been deprecated by a user to use the Google Drive api. Please edit your question and include your code.  We need to see your authorization as well as how you are making the call.  This link is not enough of an example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, an application we had running for years suddenly stopped working in mid-March of this year.    I found the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411345/download-file-from-google-drive-on-server).

In summary, the download url returned (content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/FileID?alt=media) no longer works.   Instead use this url -  googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/FileID?alt=media